# Make user change value of Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, textbox

I have a problem where i want to let the user input their name in a text field and make that change a value in javascript

`

```
Splain.addEntry({
  people:{
    all:["{{THISNEEDSINPUT}}"],
},
```

How can i make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```html
<input id="name-input" />
```

```js
const obj = {
  people: {
    all: [ "{{THISNEEDSINPUT}}" ]
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('name-input')

  input.onkeydown = () => {
    obj.people.all[0] = input.value
  }
}

Splain.addEntry(obj)
```

Comment: i got it to work, thank you very much ! only had to add a } above window.onload.